# Android ObjectAnimator Start offset

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I've tried looking all around google and various stack questions but can't seem to find anything similar to what I'm doing.

Basically, I just want to start a given ObjectAnimator animation at a certain offset of the animation (e.g. 30% through the animation, or 70% through the animation) rather than starting it from the beginning.

I'm not sure if I should be using a specific Interpolator or if there is a similar function to animation.setStartTime(). I've been using [this guide heavily](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) but can't seem to find anything in the API for setting the initial timeline of an animation to begin.

Maybe I need to be using keyframes? But I'm not sure how to sync up a keyframe to just start at 30% or 50% or 70% of the way through.

I just need to be pointed in the right direction, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can also use `.setStartDelay` with a long in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`setCurrentFraction()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setCurrentFraction(float))

> Sets the position of the animation to the specified fraction.

So setting the animation to an offset of 30% could be achieved with

```
animator.setCurrentFraction(0.3f);
```

Comment: I can't believe I didnt see this haha, yes thank you this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there an alternative for an API before 22?

Comment: @Jonas `setCurrentPlayTime()` in conjunction with `getDuration()` could do the same.